# warning comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: c

Estoy trasladando ejercicios de javascript a C, y me estanque con los condicionales.

Cuando doy a ejecutar, me toma los valores para numero1 y numero2. Sin embargo al seleccionar un operador (+, -, *, /) como lo especifique yo mismo, salta a la linea 30 saliendome como "No seleccionaste ningun operador." y finaliza ahi.

Tambien antes de ejecutarlo, me aparece en el compilador en las lineas 21, 23 , 25, 27, "[warning] comparison between pointer and integer".

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    
    float numero1, numero2;
    
    printf("Escriba dos numeros con los que desee operar ");
    scanf("%f %f", &numero1, &numero2);
    
    float suma = numero1 + numero2;
    float resta = numero1 - numero2;
    float multiplicacion = numero1 * numero2;
    float division = numero1 / numero2;
    
    int operador = 0;
    
    printf("Seleccione el operador (+, -, *, /) ");
    scanf("%i", &operador);
    
    // FALLA MASIVA
    if (operador == "+") {
        printf("La suma es de: %.2f", suma);
    } else if (operador == "-"){
        printf("La resta es de: %.2f", resta);
    } else if (operador == "*"){
        printf("La multiplicacion es de: %.2f", multiplicacion);
    } else if (operador == "/"){
        printf("La division es de: %.2f", division);
    } else {
        printf("No seleccionaste ningun operador. ");
    }
    
    system("PAUSE");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los caracteres se encierran entre comillas simples `''`, no dobles `""`. Por ejemplo es `'+'` y no `"+"`

El programa quedaría así:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{

    float numero1, numero2;

    printf("Escriba dos numeros con los que desee operar ");
    scanf("%f %f", &numero1, &numero2);

    float suma = numero1 + numero2;
    float resta = numero1 - numero2;
    float multiplicacion = numero1 * numero2;
    float division = numero1 / numero2;

    char operador;

    printf("Seleccione el operador (+, -, *, /) ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c", &operador);

    if (operador == '+')
    {
        printf("La suma es de: %.2f", suma);
    }
    else if (operador == '-')
    {
        printf("La resta es de: %.2f", resta);
    }
    else if (operador == '*')
    {
        printf("La multiplicacion es de: %.2f", multiplicacion);
    }
    else if (operador == '/')
    {
        if (numero2 != 0)
        {
            printf("La division es de: %.2f ", division);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("No se puede realizar la division, revise segundo valor");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("No seleccionaste ningun operador. ");
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Adicionalmente, recomiendo usar `getch()` y no `system("pause")` porque este último es de C++ y no de C. Recordar que en Windows `getch()` se usa con la librería `conio.h`

3 Operador es un `char`, no es del tipo `int`

Podría usarse un `switch` en lugar de `if` anidados